# Does ProBiora3 promote tooth and gum health?

Tags: medical-science, dentistry

Oragenics advertises on their website the benefits of [ProBiora3](http://www.oragenics.com/probiotics/overview):

> Oral probiotics are live bacteria that are similar (or identical) to the beneficial microorganisms found naturally in the oral cavity. The addition of oral probiotics to an oral care regimen can restore the natural balance of beneficial bacteria, which can be depleted by diet, stress, medication, illness or other factors. Oral probiotics support tooth and gum health, whiten teeth and freshen breath. Oragenics has developed oral probiotics for humans and for pets.

Is there evidence that shows that oral probiotics like ProBiora3 increase teeth and gum health or are like most supplements not evidence-based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Referring to Anna Haukioja in [2010](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2897872/), recommendation of oral probiotics for dental health purposes is not yet justified.

> Several health-promoting effects of probiotic bacteria are well documented, and there is no reason to restrict the use of probiotic products because their effects on oral health are not yet well understood; however, their recommendation for dental health purposes is not yet justified.

2. Referring to Pavitra Rastogi in [2011](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3304224/), systematic studies and randomized control trials are needed to find out the best probiotic strains and means of administration in different oral health conditions.

> Several health-promoting effects of probiotics are well documented, but their effect on oral health is not clear. Scientific evidence is poor in this area and their recommendation for oral health purposes is not yet justified. The main hurdle in this is the development of strains which can resist the oral environmental conditions and can stay there long enough to bring effect. Genetic modification of probiotic strains to suit the oral conditions is thus needed. Systematic studies and randomized control trials are therefore needed to find out the best probiotic strains and means of administration in different oral health conditions.

3. Referring to Bizzini B et.al. in [2012](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22632388), further evidence is needed to fully explore the potential of probiotics for preventing malodour.

> Many of the clinical studies are pilot in nature and with low quality, therefore, properly conducted clinical trials, using probiotic strains with in vitro proven periodontal probiotic effects, are needed. The putative beneficial effects of probiotics on oral malodour have also been evaluated, but further evidence is needed to fully explore the potential of probiotics for preventing malodour.